# Replacing function with a generator results in only one iteration

Tags: python, generator, pyodbc

The below code prints all table and columns names from an Access database:

```
import pyodbc

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=O:\MAP\05_Reporting\2018_MAPDB_NewServer_Playground.accdb;'
    r'PWD=L56dx09b2syijhr;'
    r'UID=repMAP;'
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

table_names = [table_info.table_name for table_info in cursor.tables()]
table_names_gen = (table_info.table_name for table_info in cursor.tables())

for table_name in table_names:
    print(f'TABLE NAME: {table_name}')
    for row in cursor.columns(table=table_name):
        print(f'    COLUMN NAME: {row.column_name}')
```

It works, however, if - for efficiency - I replace `for table_name in table_names` with `for table_name in table_names_gen`, it will only print first table name and its columns' names.

What might be the reason?

Comment: Try passing `cnxn` to `get_table_names` and have that function allocate its own cursor object (instead of sharing the same cursor object with the calling code which subsequently calls `cursor.columns` and changes the state of the cursor).

Comment: Thanks, `table_names_gen = (table_info.table_name for table_info in cnxn.cursor().tables())` worked! Would you mind posting an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `table_names_gen` generator is using the Cursor object named `cursor`, and while you are looping over the results of that generator you are also using the `cursor` object to retrieve the column names, thereby clobbering the state of the `cursor` object and preventing the generator from continuing. Your generator needs its own Cursor object, e.g.,

```python
table_names_gen = (table_info.table_name for table_info in cnxn.cursor().tables())
```